# JSP Custom tags disables use of anything else

Tags: html, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm trying to make a simple login with JSP, and I have a custom tag like this

`<h:mainwrapper>`

with some simple div's inside... and what i'm trying to do is to execute `<%=error %>` inside that custom tag.

I get the following error:

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /login.jsp(38,8) Scripting elements ( &lt;%!, &lt;jsp:declaration, &lt;%=, &lt;jsp:expression, &lt;%, &lt;jsp:scriptlet ) are disallowed here.`

Code-example:

```
    <h:mainwrapper>
        <h:topempty />
        <div style="margin: auto; width: 300px; height: 300px; border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 100px;">
            <div style="width: 170px; height: 250px; margin: auto; text-align: center;">

                <form action="LoginCheck" method="post">
                    <p>Login name:</p>
                    <input type="text" name="loginname" />
                    <p>Password:</p>
                    <input type="password" name="loginpass" /><br />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
                </form>

                <div style="color:#f00;">
                    <%=error %>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </h:mainwrapper>
```

Do I have to enable something to let this be allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use EL. Assuming that `error` is been set as an attribute in page, request, session or application scope, then you can just do

```
${error}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Another question though; what about if you want to iterate through a list with EL?

Comment: Use JSTL `<c:forEach>`. For more, see also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202

Comment: It's pretty simple though. Just drop JAR in classpath (if your servletcontainer didn't already ship with it out the box, like Tomcat) and declare taglib in top of JSP. That's all. It's at least **much better** than using an ugly *scriptlet*.

Comment: I was hoping that I could still use Java-coding style instead of JSTL. Afterall - is why I wanna hold onto JSP instead of JSF (which is IMO, way too heavy and configurable-needed than JSP). Thanks for clarifying though :)

Comment: JSF makes it even more simple, certainly if you use the JSP's successor Facelets.